# Order array of hashes by name but keep names with same id together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array of hashes:

```
  [{:name=>"Albert", :id=>"1"},
  {:name=>"Billy", :id=>"3"},
  {:name=>"Carol", :id=>"4"},
  {:name=>"Dennis", :id=>"2"},  
  {:name=>"Ellen", :id=>"1"}, 
  {:name=>"Frank", :id=>"5"},
  {:name=>"Gerald", :id=>"3"}]
```

I need to sort and have the result be:

```
  [{:name=>"Albert", :id=>"1"},
  {:name=>"Ellen", :id=>"1"},
  {:name=>"Billy", :id=>"3"},
  {:name=>"Gerald", :id=>"3"} 
  {:name=>"Carol", :id=>"4"}, 
  {:name=>"Dennis", :id=>"2"}, 
  {:name=>"Frank", :id=>"5"}]
```

So sort names but group ids together also sorting by name.

I have tried looking at the `sort_by` method but I don't think it will work in this situation? Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the algorithm how you created the result – especially why `Dennis` is the second last entry although its `id` is smaller than the one from `Gerald`?

Comment: The result is from a similar DB query which is ordered by the `name` column. So the result will always be ordered by name. I made a mistake when creating the sample result. I have updated the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group by `id` and then sort by the first’s hash `name` value.

```
input.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.
      values.
      sort_by { |a| a.first[:name] }.
      flatten
#⇒ [{:name=>"Albert", :id=>"1"},
#   {:name=>"Ellen", :id=>"1"},
#   {:name=>"Billy", :id=>"3"},
#   {:name=>"Gerald", :id=>"3"},
#   {:name=>"Carol", :id=>"4"},
#   {:name=>"Dennis", :id=>"2"},
#   {:name=>"Frank", :id=>"5"}]
```